# MySQLi prepared statement, I'm not sure which variables need placeholders

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Along the same lines of proper coding of my queries to work with prepared statements, I have this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM photos
        WHERE g_id = ?
        LIMIT $curPage,".$totalPix;
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

The question here is, should I use the prepared statement placeholders for `$curPage` and `$totalPix` and if so, would I do it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM photos
        WHERE g_id = ?
        LIMIT ?,".?;
$gid = $i; $lm = $v1; $mt = $v2 
$stmt = $conn->prepare($randPic);
$stmt->bind_param('iii', $gid, $lm, $mt);
$stmt->bind_result($p_fname);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
```

...or are the variables `$curPage` and `$totalPix`not leaving the query open to SQL injection? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You use placeholders anywhere you're inserting "external" data. But note that placeholders can't be used for things like table/field names - only actual values.

Comment: @Marc, Many thanks for that. IS my overall structure correct though? So even with a hard-coded variable, placeholders should still be used?

Comment: well, your second version is a syntax error. `LIMIT ?,".?;` is not valid PHP, and leaves a dangling comma in the query.

Comment: @Marc, So `LIMIT ?".?;` would be correct then, yes?

Comment: no. it's a syntax error. for proper PHP, it'd be `LIMIT ?,?";`, but you can't use placeholders for LIMIT values. those you have to insert into the query using regular PHP string operations.

Comment: @Marc, That's what I was asking in the opening question where I showed the original code. Do I simply leave it as `LIMIT $curPage,".$totalPix;` ?

Comment: @wordman - I know, it's warping your mind what's going on. So look. Checkout the [`sprintf documentation`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). You're not quite *getting it*, which is imperative here, since we're talking string parsing and placeholders. `sprintf` is not the same literally, but it's the same concept more or less. If you get one, you'll get the other.

Comment: @Jared, you are correct, I don't know much about what I am doing. But every time I see the PHP manual, it makes my head explode. It's far too engineer-ish to grasp most times. I just want to know if the variables `$curPage` and `$totalPix` are leaving the query open to SQL injection.

Comment: In this case, not if you limit their means, e.g., throw an error if their values are not integers. Simplify, simplify, simplify.  If you want to pass the `LIMIT 23, 40`, then `LIMIT Rawk, Monkey Butts` should not pass muster, much less make it to the `mysqli` phase of the equation.

Comment: @Jared, Perfect! The value for `$curPage` is simply for pagination and starts at zero and is incremented or decremented based on paging back or forward, so it's always an integer. As for `$totalPix`, that number is the result of a count query on the previous page, so it's always an integer.

Comment: Always, *always* **validate** to what you expect, *then* work that value. You'll be *soooo* much better off if you get in that habit.

Comment: Jared,Many thanks...and I just don't understand what you mean I apologize...still learning and never fast enough.

Comment: That means do not trust anything that comes from POST, GET or whatever other means you've acquired a value. If you expect `$test` to be between `10` and `20`, if it's not, **throw an error**. Doesn't matter if you *would have shown* something else. The value submitted isn't trusted because it's not right. It's a security mindset.

Comment: @Jared...Now THAT I get. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the ? on the right place (since it can only be used for variable binding).  However it is not safe to simply place `$curPage or $totalPix` in your query. I am assuming they have to be integers, so it is not really hard to make that safe.

Use `intval($curPage) and intval($totalPix)` to be certain they are.

However, if you want to allow strings it is a bit more difficult. Not sure if it is thé solution, but my bet is to 'whitelist' possible options by checking if it is something you designed it for.

For instance: `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE $somevar = ?` The variable ($somevar) could still be `'1 --'` which would return all the rows. But most likely you mean $somevar = 'id' or $somevar = 'email'. Which can easily be checked by some if statements and it wouldn't hurt performance. Maybe a little typing, but if your not in the mood to type I suggest using some framework for queries or ORM of some kind.

`if ($somevar !== 'id') exit('Cannot find entries');` at the start of the function or page

Comment: Wow, you guys are really cool, this info, although a bit over my head, is very helpful. I mentioned this to Jared: 'The value for $curPage is simply for pagination and starts at zero and is incremented or decremented based on paging back or forward, so it's always an integer. As for $totalPix, that number is the result of a count query on the previous page, so it's always an integer.' None of it is user-inputted data. I'm just wanting to avoid the dangers of SQL injection.

Comment: @wordman, **validate** your data before using it. It's that simple. Once you learn *how* to see data, you'll understand it's not too difficult to predict the variance of the data that's accessible. So, if `monkey butt` is submitted, it should **not** be used, but if `20` is, you **can** use that, since you *expect* the submitted value to be something *like* that.